# No console output for specific project - Java Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, console

I am not getting any output on the tab for "Console" for a Java program in Eclipse.  But it's only that project.  Another project I have works fine - I right click on the project after starting the server and choose Run on Server and I get output to the Console tab about all that is occurring until the project page opens.  This other project WAS giving me output to the Console tab last week, today, nothing.  I'm not sure if there was something else I clicked that turned off the output when trying to add an external jar last week.  Is there some setting in Eclipse that turns off Console output when doing Run On Server for a project?

Answer (score 0):

Finally found that I had to go to the Servers tab and under my JBoss server, remove the project, then go to Run As -> Run On Server and it re-opened the project under JBoss Server AND started outputting to the Consoles tab again.  Not sure the reason for having to do that, but it worked.